# Как убрать повторяющиеся фрагменты кода?

Tags: javascript, html, инспекция-кода

По клику отображается текст по словам

```html
<span style="background:#000000;color:black;"
 onclick="this.style.background='inherit';this.style.color='inherit'">
 Stack
 </span> 
<span style="background:#000000;color:black;" 
onclick="this.style.background='inherit';this.style.color='inherit'">
Overflow
</span>
на 
<span style="background:#000000;color:black;" 
onclick="this.style.background='inherit';this.style.color='inherit'">
русском
</span>
— 
<span style="background:#000000;color:black;" 
onclick="this.style.background='inherit';this.style.color='inherit'">
это
</span> 
<span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="this.style.background='inherit';this.style.color='inherit'">
сайт
</span>
 <span style="background:#000000;color:black;" 
onclick="this.style.background='inherit';this.style.color='inherit'">
вопросов
</span>
и 
<span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="this.style.background='inherit';this.style.color='inherit'">
ответов
</span> 
<span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="this.style.background='inherit';this.style.color='inherit'">
для
</span>
 <span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="this.style.background='inherit';this.style.color='inherit'">
 профессиональных
</span> 
<span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="this.style.background='inherit';this.style.color='inherit'">
разработчиков
</span> 
<span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="this.style.background='inherit';this.style.color='inherit'">
программного
</span> 
<span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="this.style.background='inherit';this.style.color='inherit'">
обеспечения
</span>, 
<span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="this.style.background='inherit';this.style.color='inherit'">
энтузиастов
</span> 
<span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="this.style.background='inherit';this.style.color='inherit'">
программирования
</span> и 
<span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="this.style.background='inherit';this.style.color='inherit'">
системных
</span>
 <span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="this.style.background='inherit';this.style.color='inherit'">
 администраторов
 </span>.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('censored')) {
    event.target.classList.remove('censored')
  }
})
```

```css
.censored {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: black;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<span class=censored>Stack</span> <span class=censored>Overflow</span> на <span class=censored>русском</span> — <span class=censored>это</span> <span class=censored>сайт</span> <span class=censored>вопросов</span> и <span class=censored>ответов</span> <span class=censored>для</span> <span class=censored>профессиональных</span> <span class=censored>разработчиков</span> <span class=censored>программного</span> <span class=censored>обеспечения</span>, <span class=censored>энтузиастов</span> <span class=censored>программирования</span> и <span class=censored>системных</span> <span class=censored>администраторов</span>.
```

PS: http://caniuse.com/#search=classList

Answer (score 3):

Выносим новые стили в css-класс. Проходимся по элементам и навешиваем обработчик клика в цикле.

```js
var span = document.querySelectorAll('span');
for(var i = 0; i < span.length; i++) {
  span[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.add('new');
  });
}
```

```css
span {
  cursor: pointer;
  background:#000000;
  color:black;
}
span.new {
  background: inherit;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<span>Stack</span> <span>Overflow</span> на <span>русском</span> — <span>это</span> <span>сайт</span> <span>вопросов</span> и <span>ответов</span> <span>для</span> <span>профессиональных</span> <span>разработчиков</span> <span>программного</span> <span>обеспечения</span>, <span>энтузиастов</span> <span>программирования</span> и <span>системных</span> <span>администраторов</span>.
```

Comment: С цветами немного беда, но этот ответ корректней моего :)

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych , для body пришлось додумывать, но всё намного проще оказалось :)

Answer (score 2):

Нужно вынести обработку клика в отдельную функцию :

```js
function myFunc(e) {
  e.style.background = 'inherit';
  e.style.color = 'inherit';
};
```

```html
<span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="myFunc(this)">Stack</span> <span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="myFunc(this)">Overflow</span> на <span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="myFunc(this)">русском</span>— <span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="myFunc(this)">это</span> <span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="myFunc(this)">сайт</span> <span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="myFunc(this)">вопросов</span> и
<span
  style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="myFunc(this)">ответов</span> <span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="myFunc(this)">для</span> <span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="myFunc(this)">профессиональных</span> <span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="myFunc(this)">разработчиков</span>  <span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="myFunc(this)">программного</span> <span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="myFunc(this)">обеспечения</span>, <span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="myFunc(this)">энтузиастов</span>  <span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="myFunc(this)">программирования</span> и <span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="myFunc(this)">системных</span> <span style="background:#000000;color:black;" onclick="myFunc(this)">администраторов</span>.
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let span = document.querySelectorAll('.blocks-black > span');
Array.from(span).forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.style.background = 'inherit';
    e.target.style.color = 'inherit';
  });
});
```

```css
.blocks-black span {
  background: #000000;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks-black">
  <span>Stack</span> <span>Overflow</span> на <span>русском</span> — 
  <span>это</span> <span>сайт</span> <span>вопросов</span> и 
  <span>ответов</span> <span>для</span> <span>профессиональных</span> 
  <span>разработчиков</span> <span>программного</span> <span>обеспечения</span>, <span>энтузиастов</span> 
  <span>программирования</span> и <span>системных</span> <span>администраторов</span>.
</div>
```